# Сравнение двух шифров

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Я написал небольшую программу на Python, которая зашифровывает и расшифровывает текст двум шифрами - Цезаря и Виженера. Я хочу сделать анализ данных шифров, например сравнить быстродействие шифрования или что-то подобное. Можете посоветовать, как можно сделать подобный анализ?

Comment: ответ не тут? <https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/19_concurrent_connections/measure_script_execution_time.html>

Comment: Скормить один и тот же (длинный) текст и замерить время. Желательно в цикле на много раз.